# Unsupported operand type(s)

Tags: python

```
def  double(n1):
    print  2 * n1

def triple(n):
   print  3 * n

def add(a,b):
   print double(a) + triple(b)

double(4)
triple(5)
add(3,5)
```

But i'm getting the below mentioned error, Help me out

```
8
15
6
15

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "python", line 35, in <module>

  File "python", line 28, in add

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'
```

Answer (score 4):

You are not returning from the methods `double` and `triple` . Hence the issue.

If nothing is returned, by default the method returns a `None`

Change your defintions to:

```
def  double(n1):
    #print  2 * n1
    return 2 * n1

def triple(n):
   #print  3 * n
   return  3 * n
```

Here,

```
def add(a,b):
   print double(a) + triple(b)
```

would be fine, unless you would use the return value in further processing. I shall let you figure out all the other error checks by yourself (return value of `double`, `triple`, etc.. )

Answer (score 0):

You don't return anything, therefore the `None`. Just change your `print`s to `return`s:

```
def  double(n1):
   return  2 * n1

def triple(n):
   return  3 * n

def add(a,b):
   return double(a) + triple(b)

double(4)
triple(5)
add(3,5)
```